# How to select values with the higher occurences from several matrices having the same size in matlab?

Tags: matlab, matrix

I would like to have a program that makes the following actions:

- Read several matrices having the same size (1126x1440 double)
- Select the most occuring value in each cell (same i,j of the matrices)
- write this value in an output matrix having the same size 1126x1440 in the corresponding i,j position, so that this output matrix will have in each cell the most occurent value from the same position  of all the input matrices.

Comment: Are the values real or integer? What happens if all the values are represented only once in all matrices? How many matrices do you want to process at one time? How do you store in matlab? in some cell array, or simply as variables?

Comment: Hello angainor, the values are integers and ranges from 0 to 99. the values cannot happens only once in all the matrices. there are 250 matrices to process at one time and i want to store the output matrix as a simple variable in matlab if this is possible. this matrix will have in each cell (same i, j than the other matrices) the most occurent value among 0-->99

Comment: in case it is not clear enough, the program have to check the number of occurences of 0-->99 in each i,j of the 250 matrices and then store the value in the i,j of the output matrix (same size)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code you need. I have introduced a number of constants:

```
nmatrices - number of matrices
n, m      - dimensions of a single matrix
maxval    - maximum value of an entry (99)
```

I first generate example matrices with rand. Matrices are changed to vectors and concatenated in the CC matrix. Hence, the dimensions of CC are [m*n, nmatrices]. Every row of CC holds individual (i,j) values for all matrices - those you want to analyze.

```
CC = [];
% concatenate all matrices into CC
for i=1:nmatrices
    % generate some example matrices
    % A = round(rand(m, n)*maxval);
    A = eval(['neurone' num2str(i)]);
    % flatten matrix to a vector, concatenate vectors
    CC = [CC A(:)];
end
```

Now we do the real work. I have to transpose CC, because matlab works on column-based matrices, so I want to analyze individual columns of CC, not rows. Next, using histc I find the most frequently occuring values in every column of CC, i.e. in (i,j) entries of all matrices. histc counts the values that fall into given bins (in your case - 1:maxval) in every column of CC.

```
% CC is of dimension [nmatrices, m*n]
% transpose it for better histc and sort performance
CC = CC';
% count values from 1 to maxval in every column of CC
counts = histc(CC, 1:maxval);
```

counts have dimensions [maxval, m*n] - for every (i,j) of your original matrices you know the number of times a given value from 1:maxval is represented. The last thing to do now is to sort the counts and find out, which is the most frequently occuring one. I do not need the sorted counts, I need the permutation that will tell me, which entry from counts has the highest value. That is exactly what you want to find out.

```
% sort the counts. Last row of the permutation will tell us, 
% which entry is most frequently found in columns of CC
[~,perm] = sort(counts);

% the result is a reshaped last row of the permutation
B = reshape(perm(end,:)', m, n);
```

B is what you want.

Comment: Thank you for your answer angainor. I'm trying your code now, i will tell you if it is ok. best regards

Comment: @Zied do that. I hope I understood you correctly. If not, let me know. The size and number of your matrices is quite large, so I guess you will need a few gigs of ram ;)

Comment: @Zied, @angainor, note that MATLAB also contains a function called `mode` that will return the most frequent element within a vector or matrix. Using that function, you can construct a matrix that is `CC = [n * m * nummatrices]` and then compute `B = mode(CC, 3)`;

Comment: @angainor I need to preallocate an empty matrix when constructing C because otherwise it takes a lot of memory. I tried this but there is a problem : CC=zeros(30,1625304);
nmatrices=30;
m=1446;n=1124;
maxval=99;
for i=1:nmatrices
    A=round(rand(m,n)*maxval);
    CC(i,:)=A;
end

Comment: then if i have my matrices loaded in the workspace (250 of 1446x1124), how can i include them in you code ?

Comment: @Zied I have updated the answer. Instead of randomizing A I get it from one of your neurone matrices. You will need a lot of ram for that, does not matter if you preallocate or not. You need to load all your matrices, and you need to construct CC. You could decrease the memory requirements in two ways. 1) load one 'neurone' matrix at a time, append it to CC, and clear it. 2) you could process the matrices in columns. Then you would not need to load them entirely into the workspace, but column by column. Depends what are the matrices, how and where they are stored etc.

Comment: the matrices are stored in hdf files, may be the first option is good (load append and clear)

Comment: @Zied try it. Depends how much ram you have. A simple calculation shows that you need at least 8*1446*1124*250 = 3.2GB just to host CC. Then you need counts (1.3 GB) and some extra space for loading the matrices etc. better have an 8GB system with you.

Comment: @angainor yes i think so, i will try in another system. Then the B matrix is 1446x1124 matrix containing the most occurent value from the original matrices ??

Comment: @Zied that is correct. I suggest you try it and look at the results for smaller matrices. Also, note thatt if two values have the same number of occurrences, one arbitrary is chosen. Thus, you might see differences wrt. mode solution given by cjh.

Comment: @angainor actually my values in the matrices ranges from -999 to 99 because -999 correspond to no data. So should I simply replace 1 by -999 in the following ?  counts = histc(CC, 1:maxval);

Comment: @Zied No, you can not do that since -999 will be counted as well. Instead, change -999 to a NaN in the input matrices.

Comment: @angainor i'm trying to run your script into a loop to avoid opening my matrices one by one. I'll let you know

Comment: Yes it works!!! I posted this question because i'm trying to make synthesis maps and you saved my life man !!! thanks a lot

Answer (score 3):

Building on @angainor 's answer, I think there is a simpler method using the `mode` function.

```
nmatrices - number of matrices
n, m      - dimensions of a single matrix
maxval    - maximum value of an entry (99)
```

First organize data into a 3-D matrix with dimensions [n X m X nmatrices]. As an example, we can just generate the following random data in a 3-D form:

```
CC = round(rand(n, m, nmatrices)*maxval);
```

and then the computation of the most frequent values is one line:

```
B = mode(CC,3);   %compute the mode along the 3rd dimension
```

Comment: +1, good thing to know. However, for some reason my code is ~50 times faster, at least for the system I tried... :)

Comment: Hmm, I noticed that `mode` is not a built-in function, so it could well be slower than a purpose-built solution. Strange that it is that _much_ slower, though!